# AngularJS - Remove two warnings from Chrome Console

Tags: angularjs

I am preparing to deliver a Release Candidate of an Angular Application but there are two warning in the Chrome console that I can't seem to get rid of.

The warnings:

```
'Attr.textContent' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead. [aph.js:141]
```

and

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. [jquery.js:8556]
```

I just upgraded to the latest jquery and I can't find out what "aph.js" is. I would appreciate any help because I don't want to call it a Release Candidate with warnings in the console.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning could be anything, but the name `textContent` is used by HTMLElement nodes. It is not deprecated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

The second warning means XMLHttpRequest was used with async disabled. The main JavaScript thread will be blocked until the HTTP request is finished.

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

It's a very rare but a bad thing to be doing in the code.

Neither of these warnings should affect the operation of the app.

Comment: thanks for the reassurance. I did find out that the first issue was a Chrome extension which I removed and the warning went away.

Comment: @jgravois oh that's happen to me a few times. The worse are the extensions that are suppose to improve your security.